# What is desktop manager of Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, desktop, icons, wallpaper

What is the desktop manager in Linux Mint? I mean the program which handle icons on desktop, wallpapers, etc. -- I don't mean DE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desktop icons are handled by the file manager, which is

- *Nemo* in Cinnamon Edition
- *Caja* in MATE Edition
- *Thunar* in Xfce Edition

With KDE there's a special case, as there are no icons directly on the desktop. Here, desktop icons are held by certain widgets, which are AFAIK controlled by the desktop environment.

Wallpapers are being managed by the desktop environment itself, no matter which file manager.

Comment: Thanks, because i have ubuntu and i replaced nautilus with nemo, but nemo cant handle wallpapers :(